# PuDB: Changing the window width?

Tags: pudb

PuDB allows windows to be resized vertically with the "+/-/=" keys.

How do I resize horizontally, changing the relative widths of the windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `pudb`'s help screen (which can be shown using the `?` key

```
Sidebar-related (active in sidebar):
    +/- - grow/shrink sidebar
    _/= - minimize/maximize sidebar
    [/] - grow/shrink relative size of active sidebar box
```

That last line is unfortunately a bit ambiguous, but it covers what you are looking for. These keys work when "in the sidebar", i.e. when you use `right-arrow` key to enter the `Variables` pane, and then use arrow keys to reach the `Stack` pane or `Breakpoints` pane:

1. The `+` key will "grow the sidebar", which means it will push the divider to the left, increasing the sidebar's width
2. The `-` key will "shrink the sidebar", which means it will push the divider to the right, decreasing the sidebar's width
3. The `]` key will "grow the sidebar box", which means it will increase the height of whichever pane you are in: `Variables` or `Stack` or `Breakpoints`
4. The `[` key will "shrink the sidebar box", which means it will decrease the height of whichever pane you are in: `Variables` or `Stack` or `Breakpoints`